# Determine whether a cookie was set

Tags: php

Is there a straightforward way to test whether a cookie has been set during the current request?  I'm writing an extension to existing code, so I can't modify the current code to add something like `$_COOKIE['something'] = $someValue;`.  Unfortunately, only setcookie is called, without the event being logged in any other way.  I need to know before the client receives the headers, because I need to set the cookie if the existing code hasn't already done so.

Comment: It strikes me that one should not be trying to determine what your thread of execution has previously done by trying to poll its output history.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **isset**?

```
if( ! isset($_COOKIE['something'])) {
    $_COOKIE['something'] == $somevalue;
}
```

Comment: The cookie doesn't exist in the browser yet, so it's not in `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my "brute force" solution for now.  I'm hoping to find a better method, though.  Note that `headers_list()` gets the headers that are going to be sent *to* the browser as part of the response, **not** the headers that were sent *by* the browser during the request.

```
foreach (headers_list() as $header) {
    list($k, $v) = explode(': ', $header, 2);

    if (strtolower($k) != 'set-cookie') {
        continue;
    }

    $name = explode('=', $v, 2)[0];
    if ($name == $cookieName) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```